# How to open a popup window in web forms without ajax modelpopupextender

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I am a windows forms developer and learning asp.net. I want to open a form as show dialog, means if I click the button another form has to popup and user should not able to click the backgroung page(like alert or confirm but has to contain controls). It is possible with ajax popupextender control. I tried like

```
(Javascript)  function OpenPopup(ctrlid) {                  
              window.open("testControls.aspx?ctrlid=" + ctrlid,"List","left = 300, top=150,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,width=400,height=280");
              return false;
          }
```

and code behind

```
Button1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:return OpenPopup('" + this.txtlevel2.ClientID + "')");
```

It will open the another form but allows to click on behind page. Is there any posible to do this.

Comment: please everybody read my problem properly   I want to open a form as show dialog, means if I click the button another form has to popup and user should not able to click the back page

Answer (score 4):

use window.open()

```
 Response.Write("  <script language='javascript'> window.open('HomePage.aspx','','width=1020,Height=720,fullscreen=1,location=0,scrollbars=1,menubar=1,toolbar=1'); </script>");
```

Comment: using only this code a new window will open up..!! you will not be able to click back in this new window..!! I think that is what u want..!! use just add this code in the button click event and replace homepage.aspx with your required page..!!

Comment: sorry for confused. I mean background(parent) page not back button.

Comment: Let me know,this link may help u..!!
[disable back button](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Disable-Browser-Back-Button-Functionality-using-JavaScript.aspx)

Comment: No.. See whenever we click the popup page, the popup will open, until you close that popup user should not able to click on the parent page. https://www.call2catch.com/ click the feedback button in right side bottom. will be like facebook

Answer (score 1):

Opening a popup window is nothing do with Ajax call it a javascript function you should use

```
window.open("http://www.w3schools.com")
```

follow the link(http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) for further details

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a modal popup (which requires the user to click a control within the popup to dismiss the popup), as opposed to a mode-less popup (which you can click around it to get it to hide). The ASP.NET AJAX `PopupExtender` is a mode-less popup.

Try the ASP.NET AJAX `ModalPopupExtender`, like this:

```
<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="MPE" runat="server"
                                TargetControlID="LinkButton1"
                                PopupControlID="Panel1"
                                BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" 
                                DropShadow="true" 
                                OkControlID="OkButton" 
                                OnOkScript="onOk()"
                                CancelControlID="CancelButton" 
                                PopupDragHandleControlID="Panel3" >
    <Animations>
        <OnShowing> ..  </OnShowing>
        <OnShown>   ..  </OnShown>    
        <OnHiding>  ..  </OnHiding>            
        <OnHidden>  ..  </OnHidden>            
    </Animations>
</ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
```

Look at [ModalPopup Demonstration](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx) for a demonstration of the effect by clicking on the various links on the page.

Comment: The question is **`without ajax popupextender`.**

Comment: @Shekhar - `ModalPopupExtender` != `PopupExtender`, the concept is modal vs. mode-less. So what is your question, are you looking for a non-ASP.NET AJAX solution?